# Porting machinekey.protect encryption from .net 4.5 to .net 7.0 (c#)

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-7.0, machinekey

I'm working on porting a solution from .net 4.5.2 to .net 7.0. In this solution there is a class used to decrypt data which is encoded using MachineKey.Protect on a different device (the data is stored in a database). In .net 7.0 MachineKey.Protect no longer exists.

The original code is as follows:

```
    public class EncryptionHandler
    {
        public string Protect(byte[] data)
        {
            if (data == null || data.Length == 0) return null;
            var value = MachineKey.Protect(data);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(value);
        }

        public string Unprotect(string value)
        {
            if (value == "") return value;
            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(MachineKey.Decode(value, MachineKeyProtection.Encryption));
        }

        internal void HackMachineKey() //This is used to insert the machinekey from the other device
        {
            var getter = typeof(MachineKeySection).GetMethod("GetApplicationConfig", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            var config = (MachineKeySection)getter.Invoke(null, null);
            Console.WriteLine("Current Decryptionkey: " + config.DecryptionKey);
            var readOnlyField = typeof(ConfigurationElement).GetField("_bReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            readOnlyField.SetValue(config, false);

            config.DecryptionKey = Properties.Settings.Default.MachineKeyDecryptionKey; 
            config.ValidationKey = Properties.Settings.Default.MachineKeyValidationKey;

            readOnlyField.SetValue(config, true);
        }
    }
```

In my port to .net 7 I try to insert the keys as "purposes", but that obviously is not working:

```
    internal class NewEncryptionHandler
    {
        private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        private IDataProtector _protector;
        //ToDo: move to external config
        private string _decryptionKey = "myMachineKey";
        private string _validationKey = "myValidationKey";

        internal NewEncryptionHandler(Config config)
        {
            var provider = DataProtectionProvider.Create("EzGetSettings");
            _protector = provider.CreateProtector(config.DecryptionKey, config.ValidationKey, "MachineKeyProtection.All");
        }

        internal string Unprotect(string? value)
        {
            byte[] protectedData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( value);
            var unprotected= _protector.Unprotect(protectedData);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(unprotected);
        }
    }
```

I'm unsure how to create or config the DataProtectionProvider properly. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Following this [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection?view=aspnetcore-8.0) from the documentation.

Make sure to add this in the `Program.cs`.

```cs
builder.Services.AddDataProtection();
```

Then in your class  Dependency inject the interface `IDataProtectionProvider`
in the constructor like below:

```cs
public class NewEncryptionHandler
{
   IDataProtector _protector;

   public NewEncryptionHandler(IDataProtectionProvider provider)
   {
     _protector = provider.CreateProtector("purpose");
   }
}
```

and then in your `NewEncryptionHandler` to encrypt:

```cs
var encrypted = _protector.Protect("TEST");
```

to decrypt:

```cs
var decrypted = _protector.Unprotect(encrypted);
```

**EDIT**

An Example with Console and using the main method:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // add data protection services
    var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
    serviceCollection.AddDataProtection();
    var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();


    // Create a data protector
    var dataProtector = serviceProvider.GetService<IDataProtectionProvider>();

    // Create an instance of NewEncryptionHandler
    var newEncryptionHandler = new NewEncryptionHandler(dataProtector);

    // Call encryption and decryption methods
    var plainText = "Hello, world!";
    var encryptedData = newEncryptionHandler.EncryptData(plainText);
    var decryptedText = newEncryptionHandler.DecryptData(encryptedData);


    Console.WriteLine($"Plain text: {plainText}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Encrypted data: {encryptedData}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Decrypted text: {decryptedText}");
}
```

The `NewEncryptionHandler` Class:

```cs
public class NewEncryptionHandler
{
    private readonly IDataProtector _dataProtector;

    public NewEncryptionHandler(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtector)
    {
        _dataProtector = dataProtector.CreateProtector("purpose");
    }

    public string EncryptData(string plainText)
    {
        // Encrypt data using the data protector
        return _dataProtector.Protect(plainText);
    }

    public string DecryptData(string encryptedData)
    {
        // Decrypt data using the data protector
        return _dataProtector.Unprotect(encryptedData);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention it, but it's a console application and not a .net core application. So there is no builder. I'm not sure how to insert the service in that way, or if that's even neccesary. The main problem seems to be that I incorrectly set up the protectionprovider. My errormessage is: "Can't validate data : System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The provided payload cannot be decrypted because it was not protected with this protection provider."

Comment: Added edit on how to do this on console too, You also hadn't shared how you were calling `Protect`, but Im presuming the `_protector` calling method to encrypt/decrypt  are different.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I don't thinkt this adresses my problem: the data is encrypted on a different machine using .net 4.5 MachineKey.Protect(data); encryption, that is why I only use Decrypt. The problem I have is that I have no idea how to insert the machinekey in the IDataProtector. I think this should be done using an IXmlRepository, but I have no idea how.

Comment: [Worth a read](https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-the-data-protection-system-in-asp-net-core/)